# (SQL) Is unique(set) return true or false?

Tags: mysql, sql

Why this code wrong?

```
select id
from s
where not unique(
    select sid
    from sc
    where id=sc.sid
);
```

I want to select s.id which appear at least twice in sc

Comment: @stickybit I see it at [link](https://blog.csdn.net/mba16c35/article/details/41807717)

Comment: About what DBMS is that page in the link? Can you find a link the *official* documentation of MySQL that describes this operator? I don't thin it exists in MySQL, but maybe you prove me wrong?

Comment: UNIQUE is a constraint only in mysql, at your website is no mention that that can work in mysql

Comment: But still: [Edit] the question and provide a [example], i.e. the `CREATE` statements of the tables (paste the **text**, don't use images), `INSERT` statements for sample data (dito) and the desired result with that sample data in tabular text format.

Comment: @stickybit I see it in our textbook at first.Then I have a try but it doesn't work,so I post this question.I think you are right.(I don't know where to find the official documentation of MySQL.)

Comment: @bambi . . . The documentation for all databases is online.  Just use Google or your favorite search engine.  You might also consider getting a different textbook.  The one you have does not seem to adhere very well to the SQL language.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to select s.id which appear at least twice in sc

You can use a subquery using aggregation and a `HAVING` clause filtering for the count to be equal or more than two.

```
SELECT s.id
       FROM s s
       WHERE EXISTS (SELECT ''
                            FROM sc sc
                            WHERE sc.sid = s.id
                            GROUP BY sc.id
                            HAVING count(*) >= 2);
```